# 'setRestAPIKey' method not available in LicenceManager class

Tags: android, mapmyindia-api

```
LicenceManager.getInstance().setRestAPIKey("your_rest_api_key");
LicenceManager.getInstance().setMapSDKKey("your_java_script_key");
```

I have compiled the latest maps sdk 2.3.0. Here `.setRestAPIKey()` and `.setMapSDKKey()` methods are not working. Inside the `LicenseManager.class` I found `.setMapmyIndiaBeaconToken()` method.

Comment: I don't think this info is enough. Explain more. What does "not working" mean? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Here "not working" means I am getting syntax error. After doing research I got the solution which i had posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `LicenceManager` use `MapmyIndiaAccountManager' class.

The full implementation is

```
MapmyIndiaAccountManager.getInstance().setMapSDKKey("your_java_script_key");
MapmyIndiaAccountManager.getInstance().setRestAPIKey("your_rest_api_key");
```